# UISegmentedControl customization/extensions

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, ios-autolayout

I have three doubts about using UISegmentedControl:

**1**. How (if possible) do we customize UISegmentedControl to work as in this image?

[image]

**2**. Is there a simple way to define autolayout width constraint of UISegmentedControl that expands or contracts depending on number of segments? So in storyboard I set leading and trailing constraints but in code as I dynamically add or delete segments, the width changes.

**3**. This may be too much to ask but is there any open source custom class that allows UISegmentedControl to be scrollable if number of segments can not fit in the view?

Answer (score 2):

1. Sure... use your favorite search engine to search for `customizing UISegmentedControl` -- you'll find lots of examples.
2. Sure... don't constrain the width. Constrain the center, or just leading, or just trailing. Give it a try.
3. Sure... again, use your favorite search engine to search for `custom UISegmentedControl` -- you'll find lots of examples.

And please review: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- specifically:

> In the body of your question ... ***Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.***

---

**Edit:** to offer you a little more help, here are results from a quick Google search...

---

This is pretty much the answer to your first question (just one of many answers):

[image]

https://kenb.us/how-to-customize-uisegmentedcontrol-without-losing-your-mind
Scroll down to the section title "Pill". Just don't "round-the-corners" and you pretty much have what you want.

---

For your third question, this is just one of many examples of custom "Scrollable Segmented Control" implementations: 
https://github.com/GocePetrovski/ScrollableSegmentedControl

Comment: huh, the question is very specific -- how to get customized look as in the image.

Comment: See my edited answer - hope it gets you on your way.